# rake db:migrate gives error index name already exists, but I cant find where else the duplicate index name would be

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

In development `rake db:migrate` works fine, generating a .sqlite3 file. In production where `rake db:migrate` adds tables to an actualy MySQL db I get the error.

```
-- create_table(:category_item_values)
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:
Index name 'index_category_item_values_on_category_item_key_id' on table 'category_item_values'
 already exists/site/db/migrate/20151218040123_create_category_i
tem_values.rb:3:in `change'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
```

So clearly the index name `index_category_item_values_on_category_item_key_id` already exists but I dont know what to change to fix the problem or how the naming convention works in this case.

here is 20151218040123_create_category_item_values.rb

```
class CreateCategoryItemValues < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :category_item_values do |t|
      t.string :key
      t.integer :key_type
      t.integer :guide_id
      t.integer :category_id
      t.text :value
      t.belongs_to :category_item_key, index: true
      t.belongs_to :category_item, index: true

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
    add_foreign_key :category_item_values, :category_items
    add_index :category_item_values, :guide_id
    add_index :category_item_values, :category_id
    add_index :category_item_values, :key_type
    add_index :category_item_values, :key
  end
end
```

and

20160430043022_add_foreign_key_cat_keys_to_category_item_values.rb

```
class AddForeignKeyCatKeysToCategoryItemValues < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_foreign_key :category_item_values, :category_item_keys
  end
end
```

plus 20160111231051_create_category_item_keys.rb just incase the duplicate is in there

```
class CreateCategoryItemKeys < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :category_item_keys do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.integer :key_type
      t.integer :submitted_by
    t.integer :approved_by
    t.integer :guide_id
    t.belongs_to :category, index: true
    t.timestamps null: false
    end
     add_foreign_key :category_item_keys, :categories
     add_index :category_item_keys, :name, unique: true
     add_index :category_item_keys, :key_type
  end
end
```

here is `category_item_values` table in the schema file

```
create_table "category_item_values", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "key"
    t.integer  "key_type"
    t.integer  "guide_id"
    t.integer  "category_id"
    t.text     "value"
    t.integer  "category_item_key_id"
    t.integer  "category_item_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",           null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",           null: false
    t.string   "slug"
  end
  add_index "category_item_values", ["category_id"], name: "index_category_item_values_on_category_id"
  add_index "category_item_values", ["category_item_id"], name: "index_category_item_values_on_category_item_id"
  add_index "category_item_values", ["category_item_key_id"], name: "index_category_item_values_on_category_item_key_id"
  add_index "category_item_values", ["guide_id"], name: "index_category_item_values_on_guide_id"
  add_index "category_item_values", ["key"], name: "index_category_item_values_on_key"
  add_index "category_item_values", ["key_type"], name: "index_category_item_values_on_key_type"
  add_index "category_item_values", ["slug"], name: "index_category_item_values_on_slug"
```

Whats clashing to cause this error?

Comment: are you using heroku?

Comment: Can you  please add the file names with the timestamp to the code snippets? I would be helpful to understand in which order the migrations would run. Can you please check the versions already exist in the `schema_migrations` table in the database?

Comment: @uzaif no im using google cloud platform

Comment: @spickermann I added the timestamps and the `category_item_values` table schema

Comment: `create_table "category_item_values"` is already in the `schema.rb` file, but the error occurs when running `20151218040123_create_category_item_values`? It feels to me like you are running the same migration twice.

Comment: @spickermann how can I clear any previous migrations and run it again to see if it happens (without having to delete the db)?

Comment: @spickermann I ran `RAILS_ENV=production rake db:migrate:reset` and it seems to work now